# Netbeans : update @author on existing classes?

Tags: netbeans, tags

I have a project with a bunch of classes but they have been made with an incomplete author tag (only my first name). Is it possible to change the existing tags? Just updating my $(user) doesn't work...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Edit -> Replace in projects` menu. It will open a new dialog.
There you can replace `@author name` for `@author name surname`.